# Getting response but not returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT cause of this issue. What is wrong with this code?

```
.then((userDetails: any) => {
                userDetails.role.forEach((singleRole) => {
                  if (singleRole.name === 'admin') {
                    console.log('here')
                    userDetails.userToken = userToken;
                    return res.status(200).json({
                      status: 'OK',
                      resultData: userDetails,
                    });
                  }
                });
                user.userToken = userToken;
                logger.info('Logged in successfully....');
                return res.status(200).json({
                  status: 'OK',
                  resultData: user,
                });
              })
```

Comment: Stop using a `.forEach()` and use a regular `for` loop.  Then, you can `return` and it will terminate the entire request handler.  Now your `return` just returns from the ``.forEach()` callback which doesn't stop the request handler form further execution.  `.forEach()` is basically obsolete these days because `for` is so much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code with for loop, it will wait for response because its not async like forEach

```
.then((userDetails: any) => {
            for(const singleRole of userDetails.role) {
              if (singleRole.name === 'admin') {
                console.log('here')
                userDetails.userToken = userToken;
                return res.status(200).json({
                  status: 'OK',
                  resultData: userDetails,
                });
              }
            });
            user.userToken = userToken;
            logger.info('Logged in successfully....');
            return res.status(200).json({
              status: 'OK',
              resultData: user,
            });
          })
```